# All sites select a filter issue

Tags: bug, ios-app

1. In landscape mode open All Sites and open Select a Filter window:

   > [image: begin]
2. Rotate device to portrait mode (Select a Filter window size was reduced):

   > [image: portrait]
3. Enable Split View mode (window disappeared, only "Done" link is visible):

   > [image: done]

---

- App Version: 1.6.5.3
- Device: iPad Air 2 (Wi-Fi)
- OS Version: Version 10.3.1 (Build 14E304)